# In Keras, how to organize multiple input features using pre-trained embedding mapping?

Tags: python, keras, lstm, rnn, embeddings

Let's say the goal is to predict weather given multiple features (temp, humidity) in the past 3 days.

**weather (y)** can be: Sunny, Cloudy, Rainy.

**Temp (X1)** can be : Hot, Cool, Cold.

**Humidity (X2)** can be: Low, Medium, High.

Let's say I have a pre-trained embedding dictionary for Temp:

```
temp_dict = {'Hot':[1,0,2], 'Cool':[2,3,0], 'Cold':[5,1,-3]}
```

And also a pre-trained embedding dictionary for Humidity:

```
humidity_dict = {'Low':[3,0,2], 'Medium':[1,3,0], 'High':[6,3,3]}
```

Let's say one dataset is

```
data_x = np.array([
    # sample 1
    [
        # Input features at timestep 1
        ['Cold', 'High'],
        # Input features at timestep 2
        ['Hot', 'Low'],
        # Input features at timestep 3
        ['Hot', 'Medium']
    ],
    # sample 2
    [
        # Input features at timestep 1
        ['Cold', 'Medium'],
        # Input features at timestep 2
        ['Cool', 'Low'],
        # Input features at timestep 3
        ['Cool', 'Low']
    ]
])
```

The labels of these two sample points are:

```
data_y = ['Sunny', 'Cloudy']
```

**My question is: how should the embedding matrix look like after using the pre-trained embedding?**

As you can see the original data_x has the shape of (2,3,2), should the embedding matrix have a shape of (2,3,6)? In that case, would the embedding matrix be the following?

```
embedded_matrix = np.array([
    # sample 1
    [
        # Input features at timestep 1
        [5,1,-3, 6,3,3],
        # Input features at timestep 2
        [1,0,2, 3,0,2],
        # Input features at timestep 3
        [1,0,2, 1,3,0]
    ],
    # sample 2
    [
        # Input features at timestep 1
        [5,1,-3, 1,3,0],
        # Input features at timestep 2
        [2,3,0, 3,0,2],
        # Input features at timestep 3
        [2,3,0, 3,0,2]
    ]
])
```

If this should be the case, how should I formulate a BiLSTM model using Keras?

If not, how should the data be preprocessed and how should I formulate a BiLSTM model for it?

Any help would be much appreciated.